# Require in javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs

What does this mean in javascript?
I have just started using ext-js. And the first line in sample header file is

```
Ext.require('Ext.tab.*');
```

What does this mean ?

Comment: it's "javascript" not "java script"

Comment: also, it's Ext.js not javascript.

Comment: This isn't generic to javascript, it's just a custom user made function. It might as well be `var Ext = {require: function(){alert("troll'd");}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That call is used for dynamic loading of classes/scripts:

[Ext - Sencha Docs - Ext JS 4.0](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-require)

So your call is dynamically loading all of the classes in the Ext.tab namespace (since you're using a wildcard expression).

Comment: I guess this is pre-defined namespace and we are loading all the classes so that we can use them in my javascript code.Am i right ?